# enable secure flag for custom header in Nginx.conf

Tags: linux, nginx, header

My requirement is to enable "secure" flag in one of the header called "_adminv2_session" but which contains a dynamic value. I was trying to enable the flag using the below configurations in nginx, but it'll create a new header with same name and assign value "/"

```
add_header Set-Cookie "_adminv2_session=/; HttpOnly; Secure";
```

But when I try without value, it gives errors,

```
add_header Set-Cookie "_adminv2_session; HttpOnly; Secure";
```

Can anyone help me on enable secure flag on the so called header in nginx ?

Screenshot of current status,

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The [`cookie-flag`](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/modules/cookie-flag/) module can add secure flag like so: `set_cookie_flag Secret HttpOnly secure SameSite;`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [proxy_cookie_path](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path) and [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) directives [like this](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12507708).

As far as I understood, you need to set your `_adminv2_session` variable value first, then to add `Secure` flag to your `Set-Cookie` header.

Also you can use directive `more_set_headers` from 3rd-party [headers_more module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/) to do you task [in one directive](https://dzone.com/articles/secure-existing-restful-services-no-need-for-chang).

```
more_set_headers 'Set-Cookie: $sent_http_set_cookie; HttpOnly; Secure';
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but we cannot assign a value to the header "_adminv2_session" because it's dynamic. So how we can overcome that issue ?

Comment: You can't assign anything dynamic with `add_header`, so you need to use another method like `proxy_cookie_path` or 3rd party module options.